# SQL Server / SSRS 2005 CASE evaluation of Parameter and NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case, reportingservices-2005

I am having what seems to be a rather simplistic issue, but its hampering what I need to do.

Essentially, I want to present all records (including NULLS) when I evaluate my `CASE` statement in my SQL.  Right now its filtering out the NULL values

Table

### fname  |  lname

steve  |   smith
NULL   |   jones

Query:

```
SELECT 
    fname, lname 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    fname = (CASE WHEN @param = 'All' THEN fname ELSE @param)
```

When I do this, it pulls Steve Smith fine, but it doesn't pull Jones. And I actually want Jones to show up as its part of a larger recordset.

The result set I am looking for is:

```
STEVE SMITH
      JONES
```

I am doing this in an SSRS 2005 Report and even when just going into the report because of the @parameter = 'All' by default, its not presenting the records that have nulls in that particular column that I am bouncing my parameter against.

Thanks in advance.

Just to add to this based on the responses.

I am evaluating @param coming into the SQL.  so when its 'All' I make the criteria for fname = fname.  Which is supposed to cancel it out and return everything (like there was no criteria), its only if the @param has a name in it that I am using it as a criteria

```
WHERE fname = (CASE WHEN fname = 'All' THEN fname ELSE @PARAM END)
```

What I am trying to get to is something like:

```
WHERE fname = (CASE WHEN fname = 'All' THEN (fname OR NULL) ELSE @PARAM END)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I could not find a SQL solution to this but in SSRS I found a way of getting around it, since this is a report that goes through SSRS.

On the front end table tablix I applied a filter with conditions.

```
=iif(Parameters!RPfname.Value="All", Parameters!RPfname.Value,Fields!fName.Value) = =Parameters!RPname.Value
```

This took the evaluation of the fname out of the database side and put it on the front end.  The records are filtered when the parameter is selected against the value presented in the parameter.

If its set to ALL it just presents the field without any filtering or evaluations.

Thanks for your efforts all.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OR` as nothing is equal to `NULL`

```
WHERE 
    @param = 'All'
OR
    fname = @param
```

Comment: The @param isn't being measured against the value.

Comment: This should return all rows if @param is 'All' otherwise it will return any row where `fname` matches param, is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like

```
SELECT 
    isnull(fname, ''), 
    isnull(lname, '') 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    fname = (CASE WHEN @param = 'All' THEN fname ELSE @param)
```

This may help display your null values

Comment: I tried this a bit ago and it still didn't like it.  I actually populated the field with 'Test' and it still didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

The OR condition can be simplified with out case

```
SELECT 
    fname, lname 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
   ( @param = 'ALL' OR fname = @param )
```

Comment: Hmm.  This isn't really the logic I am using or will work.  I am evaluating a parameter coming in.  Evaluating fname against fname is supposed to cancel them out as a criteria, but its not returning the null values

Comment: @10tTiger, if fname is nULL, the = can't be used, so it is not returning that value.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't SQL server ignore comparisons made against null values if you're not explicitly checking if it's null (or doing an isnull)?

I would try to get rid of all those nulls and see if that gets the results you want, then going through and taking out isnulls you don't need.

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM users
WHERE isnull(fname, '') = (CASE WHEN isnull(@param, '') = 'ALL' THEN isnull(fname, '') ELSE isnull(@param, '') END)
```